# Show that $L^2 ([ a, b])$ is the only inner product space among the spaces $L^P([a, b])$.

Tags: inner-products

I know that $L^2 ([ a, b])$ is an inner product space with parallelogram law. But I cannot prove it for $p \neq 2$.

Comment: Did you try to see if the parallelogram law holds for $p\neq 2$?

Comment: Excuse Me.I understand that the parallelogram law does not hold for p≠2. In general, how does this show?

Comment: Well, for a start, you can try to see why the parallelogram law does not hold, i.e. try to prove it and see where you get stuck.

Comment: Your answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302099/lp-space-not-having-inner-product