# FLT equation and Lp space

Tags: lp-spaces, angle

Consider an equation from the Fermat's Last Theorem without the integer condition (I'll call it FLT equation)
$$x^p+y^p=z^p,\tag{1}$$
where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are nonnegative real numbers and $p\ge2$.
(FLT states that if $p$ is an integer such that $p\ge3$, then the above equation has no integer valued solution.
But, this is not the point of my question.)

If $p=2$, then the equation (1) is closely related to the concept of right angle.
That is, if three points $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are vertices of a triangle in $\mathbb R^2$ and $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the lengthes of the corresponding segments (i.e. $x=\overline{YZ},\quad y=\overline{ZX},\quad z=\overline{XY}\:$), then

> $\triangle XYZ$ is a right triangle$\left(\angle Z=\frac\pi2\right)$ if and only if the equation (1) holds.

This is just the Pytagorean Theorem and its converse.

**Can we make a similar statement when $p>2$?**

A modification of (1)
$$\sqrt[p]{x^p+y^p}=z,\tag{2}$$
is somewhat similar to the definition of Lp norm.
So, I want say like

> $\triangle XYZ$ is the right triangle$\left(\angle Z=\frac\pi2\right)$ if and only if the equation (1) holds.

**in the Lp sense**.

Here is my opinion.
If $p>2$, then the Lp space (the set $\mathbb R^2$ with the L-p norm) is a normed space.
But it is not an inner product space([$l^p$ space not having inner product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302099/lp-space-not-having-inner-product)).
So it is not possible to define the notion of **angle**, where the formal definition of angle that I learned is as follow (Here $\theta$ is an angle between vectors $u$ and $v$ in an inner product space.);
$$\cos\theta=\frac{<u,v>}{||u||\cdot||v||}$$

So I think that the above statement that I made is not making any sense at all.
In other words, speaking of *angle* or *orthogonality* in a normed space without the parallogram law is just nonsense.
Am I right? Or is there any ways to relate FLT equation and the orthogonality in the Lp sense? And is the orthogonality always defined by using the concept of inner product? ($u\perp v\iff <u,v> =0$)